# How can Add new custom Section in Swagger?

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle, nswag

I want to add a new section inside `Swaggar`,

Please help me how can I do this?

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
  },
  "paths": {
  },
  "components": {
  },
  "NEWSection": { // Add New Section Here

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean adding a new section to the [Swagger UI](https://petstore.swagger.io/) web page? Or having a custom section in your OpenAPI JSON/YAML file e.g. to specify some metadata?

Comment: I want the second case:"having a custom section in your OpenAPI JSON/YAML file e.g. to specify some metadata"
and show result in swagger ui @Helen